# Tikz/Pgfplots Selectively Drawn

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I am attempting to plot both branches of a vertically-opening hyperbola onto an existing grid. When I run

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [thick,<->] (-10,0) -- (10,0) node[anchor=north west] {$x$};
\draw [thick,<->] (0,-10) -- (0,10) node[anchor=south east] {$t$};
\foreach \x in {-8,-6,-4,-2,2,4,6,8}
   \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
\foreach \y in {-8,-6,-4,-2,2,4,6,8}
    \draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};
\draw plot[domain=-1:1] ({tan(\x)},{sec(\x)});
\draw plot[domain=-1:1] ({tan(\x)}, {-sec(\x)});
%\draw plot[domain=-1:1] ({cosh(\x)}, {sinh(\x)});
%\draw plot[domain=-1:1] ({-cosh(\x)}, {sinh(\x)});

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Only the t-x axes are plotted. However, when I use the same code with the horizontally-opening hyperbola uncommented out, the horizontally opening hyperbolae are plotted. I was able to get the plots working inside an axis environement, but I'd like to use the coordinate system that I draw  instead.

Comment: Pgfmath normally uses degrees, not radians

Comment: Okay, thank you - making them tan(deg(\x)) and sec(deg(\x)) worked. However, when I insert a degree into the arguments of the cosh and sinh functions, I commented out above, I get an error that the dimension is too large. Is this because those functions blow up asymptotically and the values returned by cos(deg(-1/1)) are too large to represent on the page?

Comment: cosh and sinh are exponential, not trigonometric: (exp(x)+exp(-x))/2 and (exp(x)-exp(-x))/2 IIRC.  Computationally, radians make more sense, but for graphics people are more used to degrees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After almost one year ...

- For drawing OP diagram package `pgfplots` (btw, it is based on `tikz`) offer better support than `tikz`.
- In `tikz` and by this in `pgfplots` as well exist exist function `trig format` by which is possible at trigonometric functions determine which units its argument consider: *radians* or *degrees*. Default are degrees.
- For comparison of *trigonometric* and *hyperbolic* function in the firs must be decides, in which units the trigonometric functions should be.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=100mm,
 axis lines = center,
     xlabel = $x$,
     ylabel = $f(x)$,
     label style = {anchor=north east},
tick label style = {font=\scriptsize, minimum height=3ex, inner sep=0pt},
      xtick = {-2*pi,-1.5*pi,-pi,-0.5*pi,0.5*pi,pi,1.5*pi,2*pi},
xticklabels = {$-2\pi$,$-\frac32\pi$,$-\pi$,$-\frac12\pi$,
               $\frac12\pi$,  $\pi$, $\frac32\pi$, $2\pi$},
trig format = rad,            % <-------
    samples = 1001, 
     domain = -2*pi:2*pi,
       xmin = -7.5, xmax=7.5,
restrict y to domain=-9:9,
   no marks,
legend style = {legend pos=outer north east, anchor=north,
                legend cell align=left,
                font=\scriptsize},
every axis plot post/.append style={thick}
             ]
% trigonometric
\addplot    {tan(\x)};
% hyperbolic
\addplot    {cosh(\x)};
\addplot    {-cosh(\x)};
\addplot    {sinh(\x)} ;

\legend{$\tan(x)$, $\cosh(x)$, $-\cosh(x)$, $\sinh(x)$}
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result at `trig format = rad` is:

[image]

and when is `trig format = deg` and axis preamble is:

```
\begin{axis}[width=100mm,
 axis lines = center,
     xlabel = $x$,
     ylabel = $f(x)$,
     label style = {anchor=north east},
tick label style = {font=\scriptsize, minimum height=3ex, inner sep=0pt},
trig format = deg,            % <-------
    samples = 1001, 
     domain = -2*pi:2*pi,
       xmin = -7.5, xmax=7.5,
restrict y to domain=-9:9,
   no marks,
legend style = {legend pos=outer north east, anchor=north,
                legend cell align=left,
                font=\scriptsize},
every axis plot post/.append style={thick}
             ]
```

[image]

Comment: Well, I don't remember why I asked this, but this is what I had in mind. I hope this helps someone in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to plot the data separately.

[image: v01]

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw [thick,latex-latex] (-10,0) -- (10,0) node[anchor=north west] {$x$};
        \draw [thick,latex-latex] (0,-10) -- (0,10) node[anchor=south east] {$t$};
        \foreach \x/\y in {-8,-6,-4,-2,2,4,6,8} {
            \draw (\x cm,3pt) -- (\x cm,-3pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
            \draw (3pt,\y cm) -- (-3pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};
        }
    
        \draw plot[domain=-1:1] (\x,{tan(deg(\x))});
        \draw plot[domain=-1:1] (\x,{sec(deg(\x))});
                
%       \draw plot[domain=-1:1] (\x,{tan(deg(\x))});
        \draw plot[domain=-1:1] (\x,{-sec(deg(\x))});

        \draw plot[domain=-1:1] (\x,{cosh(\x)});
        \draw plot[domain=-1:1] (\x,{sinh(\x)});
        
        \draw plot[domain=-1:1] (\x,{-cosh(\x)});
        \draw plot[domain=-1:1] (\x,{sinh(\x)});
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Maybe you can add some colors (in `\draw` environment) for better visualisation and differentiation.